# Encoding in R : <> unicode to letter

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, rfacebook

I am having problems when extracting comments from posts using the RFacebook package.

```
localiza <- getPage(543362459038077,token = my_oauth,n=10)
post <- getPost(post = localiza$id[1], token = my_oauth) here
```

The problem is the encoding of the output. For example:

> algu/U+00E9/m

**Note that instead of "/", the output has <>**

That word, for instance, should appear as

> alguém

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider changing your `locale`.  It's not a problem with `Rfacebook`.  I can replicate the behavior you described by setting locale to `C`, e.g.

```
x <- "Boa tarde. Há alguém de plantão na agência esses dias?"
Sys.setlocale(locale = "C")
x
# [1] "Boa tarde. H<U+00E1> algu<U+00E9>m de plant<U+00E3>o na ag<U+00EA>ncia esses dias?"
```

By switching the locale for character set handling to one with an extended character set, the desired output is achieved, e.g.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
x
# [1] "Boa tarde. Há alguém de plantão na agência esses dias?"
```

The value of the `locale` argument may be different on your system. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html (or `?locales`) for more information on setting locales.